# Get the XElement for the XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xelement

Here's my XML File:

```
<Applications>
   <Application Name="Abc">
     <Section Name="xyz">
        <Template Name="hello">
         ...
         ....
         </Template>
      </Section>
   </Application>
   <Application Name="Abc1">
     <Section Name="xyz1">
        <Template Name="hello">
         ...
         ....
         </Template>
      </Section>
   </Application>
```

What I need to do is get the Template XElement from the given structure based upon the Name attribute of Template tag. The problem is there can be multiple template tags with same attribute Name. The Distinguishing factor is Application Name attribute value and section attribute value.

Currently I'm able to get the XElement by first getting Application Element based upon it's attribute, then Section based upon it's attribute and then finally template based upon it' name.

I wanted to know if there is a way to get it in one go.

Comment: You can probably achieve this by building and evaluating an XPath expression, but using LINQ to XML and your current approach is also a valid, efficient strategy. Is there a particular reason why you want to match the element "in one go"?

Comment: No particualr reason, just wanted to know if it was possible to accomplish it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code should do the trick:

```
var template = doc.Descendants("Template")
                  .Where(x => x.Attribute("Name").Value == "hello"
                           && x.Parent.Attribute("Name").Value == "xyz1"
                           && x.Parent.Parent.Attribute("Name").Value == "Abc1");
```

Please note that this code throws exceptions if the XML doesn't conform to the specification. Specifically, there will be a `NullReferenceException` if any of the tags in question don't contain an attribute named "Name". Or if the Template tag doesn't have two levels of parents.

Comment: Works like a charm, added FirstOrDefault() at the end.

Answer (score 6):

I would use the fact that you can call `Elements` or an existing sequence, so:

```
var template = doc.Descendants("Application")
                  .Where(x => (string) x.Attribute("Name") == applicationName)
                  .Elements("Section")
                  .Where(x => (string) x.Attribute("Name") == sectionName)
                  .Elements("Template")
                  .Where(x => (string) x.Attribute("Name") == templateName)
                  .FirstOrDefault();
```

You might even want to add an extension method somewhere:

```
public static IEnumerable<XElement> WithName(this IEnumerable<XElement> elements,
                                             string name)
{
    this elements.Where(x => (string) x.Attribute("Name") == name);
}
```

Then you can rewrite the query as:

```
var template = doc.Descendants("Application").WithName(applicationName)
                  .Elements("Section").WithName(sectionName)
                  .Elements("Template").WithName(templateName)
                  .FirstOrDefault();
```

... which I think you'll agree is quite readable :)

Note that the use of casting `XAttribute` to `string` instead of using the `Value` property means that any elements without the `Name` attribute are just effectively ignored rather than causing a `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: Neat and +1 for the extension method, wasn't aware of that. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("Path of xml");
    var selection =
        doc.Descendants("Section").Select(item => item).Where(
            item => item.Attribute("Name").Value.ToString().Equals("Section Name Value")).ToList();

    if(null != selection)
    {
        var template =
            selection.Descendants("Template").Select(item => item).Where(
            item => item.Attribute("Name").Value.ToString().Equals("Template name value"));
    }
```

Comment: I'm yet to try out your answer,I will get back once I do.

Answer (score 1):

XPath should help you. Use the [Extensions.XPathSelectElement Method (XNode, String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb156083.aspx) :

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("yourfile.xml");
string xPathQuery = string.Format(
    "/Applications/Application[@Name='{0}']/Section[@Name='{1}']/Template[@Name='{2}']",
    "MyApplication",
    "MySection",
    "MyTemplate"
);

XElement template = xdoc.Root.XPathSelectElement(xPathQuery);
```

Comment: As the hierarchy of nodes is known, I'd rather go with **xDoc.XPathSelectElements("/Applications/Application/Section/Template[@Name='" + templateName+ "']");** which should be more efficient

Comment: @nulltoken: This doesn't respect the OPs requirements.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth You're right. I *did* forgot to add the named restrictions for *Application* and *Section*. My point was to rather use an explicit path from the root instead of a "//template[@Name='xxxx']" query. However, it looks like the answer is already fixed :)

Comment: Yeah, I misread the question the first time. i've updated my answer in this way.